# What would be a translation of Ruby On Rails to Sequelize (or other ORMs) in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, postgresql, orm

What would be some equivalent code I would use if I am switching to Sequelize from Ruby on Rails.

If I want to go isomorphic JavaScript I will probably want to use an ORM for Node.js...

Before I invest too much time in one versus another are there any recommendations?

I have looked at Sequelize, ORM NPM, Active Record Npm, and they all look good but I'm not sure which will work best. If someone could show me some translation to their Node-equivalent ORM I would be able to implement it quickly and learn a lot about how that ORM works. Thank you.

If someone can provide a short guide on how I would translate this Ruby on Rails code to an equivalent bit of Sequelize JS or Bookshelf JS I can decide which looks most convenient.

```
  def show
    @pet = Pet.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @pet
      render json: @pet
    else
      render status: 400, nothing: true
    end
  end
  def update
    @pet = Pet.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @pet.update(pet_params)
      render json: @pet
    else
      render status: 400, nothing: true
    end
  end
private
  def pet_params
    params.require(:pet).permit(:name, :species, :author_id)
  end
```

It would make my life a lot easier thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe sequelize has the best documentation as you have probably seen in other answers.

```
app.get("Projects/:id", function (res,req){
var particularProj=Project.findById(params.id).then(function(project) {
  // project will be an instance of Project and stores the content of the table entry with id 123. if such an entry is not defined you will get null

      res.render("show.ejs", {proj: particularProj}
   });
});
```

Would be similar to the following in Ruby on Rails Active Record:

```
def show
    proj=Project.find(params[:id]);
    @proj=proj
end
```

Comment: Thanks I guess I can edit my question to match that more closely, because that's more what I was looking for anyway.